# skipping a turn of a for-loop using except

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, syntax

So I am using a function which adds components to the system via:

```
es.add(components[i][0] for i in components.keys())
```

components is a python dictionary, which looks like this:

```
components = {'a': (a0, a1),
              'b': (b0, None)}
```

What I am trying the achieve is that I want to run above mentioned `for-loop` with `except`, which will be able to not run the `add()` function if the `components` dictionary gives `None`.

What I tried:

```
es.add(components[i][1] for i in components.keys() except None)
```

Ofc it gives a syntax error. What is the syntax for it?

---

EXAMPLE:

```
es.add(components[i][1] for i in components.keys())
```

Above is equal with:

```
es.add(a1)
es.add(None)
```

I want to write my for-loop in a way it adds only `a1` and skips `None`.

Comment: What do you mean, run it "with expect"? What is `expect` in this situation?

Comment: run `add()` function if the input of the dictionary is not `None`.

Comment: Maybe he meant except?

Comment: you are right, fixed question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that it is like `[components[i][1] for i in components.keys() if type(components[i][1]) != type(None)]`

so that below code can work fine

```
es.add(components[i][1] for i in components.keys() if type(components[i][1]) != type(None))
```

Comment: Oh you are right, I should have done that with if instead of expect ^^

Comment: No need for all that `type()` stuff. `if components[i][1] is not None` would be fine.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it raise me an warning in my project. I don't know why.

Comment: would this work? `for i in components.keys() if is not None`, I want to make it short as possible. otherwise I add the `components[i][1]`

Comment: @Icedkk Short answer no, long aswer how script should know it need to look second element in array :D

Comment: yeah @İhsanCemilÇiçek you are right, anyway thanks^^

Comment: soverflow didn't let me accept an answer too fast, had to wait for 5 mins^^ @İhsanCemilÇiçek

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` condition as [`except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) is of no use in this case. You can also make it shorter and more readable by iterating the [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) directly:

```
es.add(x for _, x in components.values() if x is not None)
```